# How to create a custom exception and handle it in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, try-catch

I have written this code to test how custom exceptions are working in the dart.

I'm not getting the desired output could someone explain to me how to handle it??

```dart
void main() 
{   
  try
  {
    throwException();
  }
  on customException
  {
    print("custom exception is been obtained");
  }
  
}

throwException()
{
  throw new customException('This is my first custom exception');
}
```

Comment: Did you defined a `customException` class ? If yes, could you add its code to your question.

Comment: class customException implements Exception {
  String _message = "";
  customException([this._message]);
  
  String toString() => "LatLngException: message=${_message}";
}i solve this using this piece of code defined @AlexandreArdhuin is correct

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can look at the [Exception part of *A Tour of the Dart Language*](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#exceptions).

The following code works as expected (`custom exception has been obtained` is displayed in console) :

```dart
class CustomException implements Exception {
  String cause;
  CustomException(this.cause);
}

void main() {
  try {
    throwException();
  } on CustomException {
    print("custom exception has been obtained");
  }
}

throwException() {
  throw new CustomException('This is my first custom exception');
}
```

Comment: i want my exception to be inherited from the Exception class.

Comment: FYI : *Dart programs can throw any non-null object—not just Exception and Error objects—as an exception*

Comment: @Vickyonit do not inherit from the Exception class, implement it instead. Also, you may want to consider adding a code to the class as well.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the Exception's members to be marked as `final`?

Comment: @OlegSilkin Yes, always make things final unless mutations are a requirement. Exceptions should never mutate.

Comment: @KaiSellgren should we implement over extend because `Exception` is abstract? What about extending from concrete implementations like [`SocketException`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/04b7b090eb5dd714654faa80843c1feadc1ccede/sdk/lib/io/socket.dart#L981)?

Comment: Interesting.  new is opitonal in my version of dart, but its helpful to understand its calling the constructor in your example.

Comment: to get the custom exception instance: `on CustomException catch(e) {...`

Answer (score 55):

If you don't need to be specific about the problem, you can throw a general issue like this:

```
throw ("This is my first general exception");
```

But it's better to use specific errors when possible. They tell you more about what went wrong so you can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: With [reference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#exceptions) to "Dart programs can throw any non-null object—not just *Exception* and Error objects—as an **exception**." (emphasis mine), I've made an edit to your post because the actual type of the object thrown here is *String*, which you can verify by the following code snippet: `void main() { try { throw ("Your description is a String");} catch (e) { print(e.runtimeType); } }`

Answer (score 6):

You can also create an abstract exception.

*Inspiration taken from `TimeoutException` of `async` package (read the code on [Dart API](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/TimeoutException-class.html) and [Dart SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/a1e2432679f4d68cfb629c17d42d5018be6f370b/sdk/lib/async/future.dart#L905)).*

```dart
abstract class IMoviesRepoException implements Exception {
  const IMoviesRepoException([this.message]);

  final String? message;

  @override
  String toString() {
    String result = 'IMoviesRepoExceptionl';
    if (message is String) return '$result: $message';
    return result;
  }
}

class TmdbMoviesRepoException extends IMoviesRepoException {
  const TmdbMoviesRepoException([String? message]) : super(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Simple Custom Exception Example for Beginners

```
class WithdrawException implements Exception{
  String wdExpMsg()=> 'Oops! something went wrong';
}

void main() {   
   try {   
      withdrawAmt(400);
   }   
  on WithdrawException{
    WithdrawException we=WithdrawException();
    print(we.wdExpMsg());
  }
  finally{
    print('Withdraw Amount<500 is not allowed');
  }
}

void withdrawAmt(int amt) {   
   if (amt <= 499) {   
      throw WithdrawException();   
   }else{
     print('Collect Your Amount=$amt from ATM Machine...');
   }   
}
```

Comment: you can implement any number of exception class and call one or all.