# How to crash Flutter App for Android and iOS (to test Firebase Crashlytics)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I want to test out crash report using `Firebase Crashlytics` in my `Flutter` App. I need to Fatal crash my `flutter` app for both Android and iOS programmatically. Any idea?

Comment: take a look at this [beatiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66907505/12041701)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to throw a Dart exception by doing this anywhere in your Flutter app:

```
throw Exception("This is a crash!");
```

Or by using an arbitrary object:

```
throw "This is a crash!";
```

You can find more info about dart exceptions [in the language tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#exceptions) and if you want, you can create your own custom Exception type as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579982/custom-exceptions-in-dart)

Comment: By throwing this kind of exception app will not crash but shown exception on screen.

Comment: @BrindaRathod you are right,
this should not be the approved answer, as in it confusing...

Comment: @BrindaRathod means shown exception in console, so if you use FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash(); it will realy crash app and closing it.

Answer (score 22):

If you have the `flutter_crashlytics` plugin, you can test it using

```dart
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
```

Comment: I have tried it but not showing any crash in the firebase console any other way?

Comment: We want to send information about crashes made by ourselves, not by package. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 6):

integrate [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics#)

```
 Crashlytics.instance.crash();
```

Answer (score 4):

using firebase_crashlytics plugin

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();
```

You should enable crashlytics

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (kDebugMode) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);//disable false
  }else{
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can crash you Flutter app by many ways:

1. `throw(Exception('Hello Crashlytics'));` like in @Xavi Rigau's answer
2. 

```
List list;

list.add("add");
```

Like @Paresh Mangukiya does.

3.

```
final a = [12];
print(a[1]);
```

But there is 2 **IMPORTANT** thing you should consider:

- You should run your app in release mode, for example with the command `flutter run --release`
- In Crashlytycs console, by default shown only fatal crashes. The crashes above are non-fatal crashes. So, you should clear the filter to see all crash types. (Filter can be filtered in crashlytics dashboard by clicking (x) button near filter). More on this you can read from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637124/4693979)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. This is from the official documentation. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage

Once your configuration is proper according to documentation for crashlytics, `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();` will crash the app.