# Firebase Crashlytics crashes not being reported to the Firebase Console in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I tried to setup Firebase Crashlytics for the iOS part of the flutter app. I get the following messages in my console, but I do not see anything in the Firebase Dashboard.

> 2019-08-23 14:31:33.648772+0530 Runner[87816:826824] flutter: Flutter error caught by Crashlytics plugin:
>
> 2019-08-23 14:31:33.734996+0530 Runner[87816:826824] flutter: Error reported to Crashlytics.

1) `Pubspec.yaml`

Added `firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.0+2` added to the dependencies list

2) Main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';

void main() async {
  Crashlytics.instance.enableInDevMode = true;

  // Pass all uncaught errors from the framework to Crashlytics.
  FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

3) Added run script in Build Phases

Script - `${PROJECT_DIR}/Fabric.framework/run`
Input Files - `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

4) Adding the following to crash test on click of a button in dart.

```
throw exception ("This is a test crash");
```

5) I have also tried installing the app on the simulator, stop debug, force crash and restart again.

Here are my logs:

```
2019-08-23 14:31:29.162211+0530 Runner[87816:826814]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-08-23 14:31:29.321000+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2019-08-23 14:31:29.339518+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000033] Data Collection flag is not set.
2019-08-23 14:31:29.343569+0530 Runner[87816:826779] [Crashlytics] Version 3.13.4 (143)
2019-08-23 14:31:29.344190+0530 Runner[87816:826779] [Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone), 12.2.0 (18F132)
2019-08-23 14:31:29.351346+0530 Runner[87816:826779] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Registered Firebase Analytics event listener
2019-08-23 14:31:29.352626+0530 Runner[87816:826779] [Answers] Initialized
2019-08-23 14:31:29.374874+0530 Runner[87816:826779] [Fabric] 
    Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.4.1";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.13.4";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.10.2";
    }
2019-08-23 14:31:29.441898+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    acct = "com.vts.vtsMobileCloud";
    class = genp;
    gena = "com.google.iid";
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    "r_Data" = 1;
    svce = "com.google.iid.checkin";
}
2019-08-23 14:31:29.459396+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    atag = <636f6d2e 676f6f67 6c652e69 69642d7c 4b7c>;
    class = keys;
    "r_Ref" = 1;
    type = 42;
}
2019-08-23 14:31:29.467260+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    atag = <636f6d2e 676f6f67 6c652e69 69642d7c 507c>;
    class = keys;
    "r_Ref" = 1;
    type = 42;
}
2019-08-23 14:31:29.469687+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009000] No keypair info is found with tag com.google.iid-|K|
2019-08-23 14:31:29.470959+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009006] There's no legacy keypair so no need to do migration.
2019-08-23 14:31:29.473193+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023000] Info is not found in Keychain. OSStatus: -25300. Keychain query: {
    acct = "com.vts.vtsMobileCloud";
    class = genp;
    gena = "com.google.iid-tokens";
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    "r_Data" = 1;
    svce = "346036413985:*";
}
2019-08-23 14:31:29.475434+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902003] Monitoring the network status
2019-08-23 14:31:29.475923+0530 Runner[87816:826831] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:59771/SLPgRYC-GPQ=/
2019-08-23 14:31:29.477698+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS024000] Debug mode is on
2019-08-23 14:31:29.478350+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - 
2019-08-23 14:31:29.478853+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60101000 started
2019-08-23 14:31:29.480269+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http:)
2019-08-23 14:31:29.480999+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
2019-08-23 14:31:29.550095+0530 Runner[87816:826819] [Answers] Answers is disabled. Cleaning up.
2019-08-23 14:31:29.689894+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001008] Successfully created App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag GoogleUtilitiesAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO (Boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-08-23 14:31:29.692544+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902004] Network status has changed. Code:2, status:Connected
2019-08-23 14:31:29.694005+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031010] Tracking view controller. Class, ID: FlutterViewController, -5765211381914463904
2019-08-23 14:31:29.696012+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031013] Screen view event not logged. App is not active.
2019-08-23 14:31:29.821624+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS029014] Successfully parsed a configuration. Version: 1566456169535025
2019-08-23 14:31:29.826523+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023016] Analytics is ready to receive events
2019-08-23 14:31:29.946190+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2019-08-23 14:31:29.947722+0530 Runner[87816:826814] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled
2019-08-23 14:31:29.948368+0530 Runner[87816:826819] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics enabled
2019-08-23 14:31:30.414665+0530 Runner[87816:826814] [Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
2019-08-23 14:31:30.415103+0530 Runner[87816:826814] [Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
2019-08-23 14:31:30.511026+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS033003] Scheduling user engagement timer
2019-08-23 14:31:30.513147+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Engagement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 3600
2019-08-23 14:31:30.513984+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, screen_view (_vs), {
    ga_event_origin (_o) = auto;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = FlutterViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -5765211381914463904;
}
2019-08-23 14:31:30.514647+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: screen_view (_vs), {

        ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
        ga_event_origin (_o) = auto;
        ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
        ga_screen_class (_sc) = FlutterViewController;
        ga_screen_id (_si) = -5765211381914463904;
    }
    2019-08-23 14:31:30.703851+0530 Runner[87816:826824] flutter: addToOverlay
    2019-08-23 14:31:31.040103+0530 Runner[87816:826835] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event 
    params: screen_view (_vs), {
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = auto;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = FlutterViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -5765211381914463904;
    }

2019-08-23 14:31:31.766716+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.2573471069335938
2019-08-23 14:31:31.792724+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): -0.2573471069335938
2019-08-23 14:31:31.796034+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002001] Measurement timer fired
2019-08-23 14:31:31.798589+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
2019-08-23 14:31:31.799467+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023033] Starting data upload
2019-08-23 14:31:31.799862+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023105] Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, 
   parameters: screen_view (_vs), {
    ga_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    ga_event_origin (_o) = auto;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    ga_screen_class (_sc) = FlutterViewController;
    ga_screen_id (_si) = -5765211381914463904;
    }
2019-08-23 14:31:31.801179+0530 Runner[87816:826844] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012018] Saving bundle. size (bytes): 425
2019-08-23 14:31:31.802492+0530 Runner[87816:826844] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 61, 1566550890505
2019-08-23 14:31:32.035619+0530 Runner[87816:826844] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023038] Uploading events. Elapsed time since last successful upload (s): 242.4702870845795
2019-08-23 14:31:32.037031+0530 Runner[87816:826844] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1566550892032, <APMPBMeasurementBatch: 0x600000252560>
2019-08-23 14:31:32.050976+0530 Runner[87816:826840] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900000] Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2019-08-23 14:31:32.170464+0530 Runner[87816:826844] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
2019-08-23 14:31:32.262611+0530 Runner[87816:826835] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023044] Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
2019-08-23 14:31:32.265501+0530 Runner[87816:826821] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fd16a4875c0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-23 14:31:32.265647+0530 Runner[87816:826821] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fd16a4875c0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-23 14:31:32.266164+0530 Runner[87816:826821] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-23 14:31:32.266553+0530 Runner[87816:826821] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-23 14:31:32.268991+0530 Runner[87816:826835] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): -0.7637839317321777
2019-08-23 14:31:32.269088+0530 Runner[87816:826835] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): -0.7637839317321777
2019-08-23 14:31:32.358056+0530 Runner[87816:826821] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled
2019-08-23 14:31:32.358229+0530 Runner[87816:826821] 6.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
2019-08-23 14:31:33.648772+0530 Runner[87816:826824] flutter: Flutter error caught by Crashlytics plugin:
2019-08-23 14:31:33.734996+0530 Runner[87816:826824] flutter: Error reported to Crashlytics.
2019-08-23 14:35:59.541939+0530 Runner[87816:830344] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fd16a486530] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-23 14:35:59.542135+0530 Runner[87816:830344] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fd16a486530] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-23 14:35:59.542630+0530 Runner[87816:830344] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-23 14:35:59.542764+0530 Runner[87816:830344] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
```

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong and have been stuck with this for 2 days now. Any help or advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Crashlytics Page]

[image: Analytics Page]

Comment: Are you looking in the right place on Firebase? You mentioned you don't see anything on the Firebase Dashboard, but that's not where crashes are reported - you need to go to the Crashlytics page from the side menu. On a different note, do you get to see the analytics on Firebase Dashboard, or are those not working either? Getting analytics would indicate a correct json config file.

Comment: Yes, I am. I have edited my post with a couple of images for the Crashlytics and the Analytics Dashboard for you to view. I also notice the following in the error logs. Is this something I should be concerned about?

2019-08-23 14:35:59.542135+0530 Runner[87816:830344] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7fd16a486530] get output frames failed, state 8196

Comment: Have you tried removing the default filter of <Event type = "Crashes"> by clicking the little X next to it, on the Firebase Crashlytics page?

Comment: @Ovidiu - That is it! I had to remove the default filter. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you open the Firebase Crashlytics page, it defaults to applying the 'Event type = "Crashes"' filter. Unhandled exceptions in Flutter are technically not crashes - the Android activity is still running as the exception did not occur on the native UI thread. All Flutter exceptions are therefore logged as non-fatal crashes.

Simply remove the default filter to see both fatal and non-fatal crashes.

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: Removing the filter in the firebase crashlytics dashboard solved my issue of not seeing non-fatal errors!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you are not crashing in debug mode.

I read this in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2540#issuecomment-531439363): **In android, the app doesn't report Crash type events with debug APK**

After building a release version and installing it on my device, viola the first crash was reported.

```
flutter build apk --release && flutter install
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The errors in flutter aren't crashes so it won't be recorded as a crash.

1. Turn the filter to `non-fatals`,
2. The 2 apply plugin statements in `app/build.gradle` should be placed below dependencies section.

Make sure of that and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue [but on Android]. The screen in the Firebase console was stuck on "We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers." I got it working by doing the following:

1. Follow the instructions in FlutterFire docs to set up Crashlytics, but change the following. In app/build.gradle add the dependencies like this:

   ```
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
   ```
2. And this is how I initialised Crashlytics instance in my main.dart

   ```
    Function originalOnError = FlutterError.onError;
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) async {
       await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(errorDetails);
    originalOnError(errorDetails);
   };
   ```
3. Also add the following if you want to test in debug mode:

   ```
   await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: There is a limit/quota for the number of crashes/error reports, that firebase accepts, that is reset after a while after it was exceeded.

I reached the quota with around 100-200 error reports for multiple apps of the same firebase project. After that, no more errors showed up on a previously untested app. Changing the network did not help. Waiting a few hours did. After the period, errors showed up again.

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that non-fatal exceptions are only displayed in the Crashlytics dashboard when a fatal exception is thrown, since this causes a report to be sent to Crashlytics.

More in Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=1&hl=en&platform=flutter#report-caught-exceptions