# Flutter Crashlytics - No Crash log for non-fatal flutter error

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

We are using `firebase_crashlytics: ^0.4.0+1` in a flutter app. Within the runApp() we are starting to listen to errors and crashes just like mentioned in the documentation.

```
runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(
..
}, (error, stackTrace) {        
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
});
```

In general crashes are reported, but not for these type of crashes **EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY**.
In some circumstances objects might be null, but instead of getting a crash reported to the firebase crashlytics dashboard, nothing happens. User only receive a grey screen and that is it.
Therefore we only are notified if a user reports these errors, but we receive no logs.
Is this a non-fatal error and we should be using recordFlutterError method?

BTW, this is being called when the error is thrown:

```
    Function originalOnError = FlutterError.onError;
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) async {
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(errorDetails);
  // Forward to original handler.
  originalOnError(errorDetails);
```

Even the method `originalOnError(errorDetails)` is called the error is not recorded in the firebase crashlytics dashboard.
How can we make these non-fatal errors also be reported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logging has been done by firebase crashlytics. The default filter in the firebase console dashboard was set to `crashes`. Removing the filter and we can see all reported errors, crashes, non-fatal errors.
Thanks to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637124/3331888)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record non-fatal error log in your app.
**In my case i used it as logging all the request other then 200 from server.
you can use like this as well.**

For this you can use just this after all the configurations

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.log('Here is My custom Error for it ');
```