# Flutter. App won't crash and send crash report

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I've integrated `Firebase Crashlytics` in my app and I'm testing the Android app. I've forced a crash to check it:

```
if (true){
  List arr = [];
  throw arr[1] =2;
}
```

My problem is that the app doesn't crash. I just get this in the logs but it won't crash in order for Crashlytics to send the stacktrace to the server.

`E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1`

[image]

Why is this happening and why is this not "working properly".

I know one would not want to have their app crash, but ... how will I know if the app crashes while in production?

P.S. Testing with `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash()` works on the other hand. App crashes and sends the report. Why does that work?!

Comment: Because the thing you tried above is throwing a runtime exception and not crashing your app.

Comment: Hmm .. and how do I make it crash though ? I mean ... I'm sure I'll have that type of exception in my code at some point. Trying to use a list item from an index that is out of bounds. And if it won't crash the app and thus not trigger Firebase to send the crash, I won't know about it. Am i right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was faced with the same issue and found answers to your questions and solution that works.

> Why is this happening and why is this not "working properly"

According to Crashlytics there are two types of events: Crashes and Non-fatals.
Unhandled Exceptions like yours treated as Non-fatal events and Crashlytics doesn't record them by default.
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/reports#filtering-crash-types

> but ... how will I know if the app crashes while in production?

You can enable recording of Non-fatals by doing this in main.dart

```
FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
```

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage#handling-uncaught-errors

> P.S. Testing with FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash() works on the other hand. App crashes and sends the report. Why does that work?!

Because FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash() causes the app to crash natively.
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_crashlytics/latest/firebase_crashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics/crash.html

---

From comments:

> I think it's more frustrating for the user if he clicks and nothing happens as opposed to the app crashing. If it crashes, it's clear then what has happened, there's an issue, as opposed to nothing happening and leaving the user flabbergasted...

Additionally to submitting a report of a non-fatal errors you can implement one of the following scenarios:

1. Terminate an app (simulate a crash)

exit(0) terminates an app and doesn't report additional crash to Crashlytics

```
FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(details);
    exit(0);
};
```

2. Display some alert like "Something went wrong"

Probably display an alert is better depending on data your application processing and nature of operations.

Comment: Oh, wow. Finally! An elaborated answer. Allow me one question ... I would still like to offer visual feedback to the user if the app crashes (i.e crash the app). Instead of, for instance, the clicking on a button not working, and having nothing happen when you do so, I'd still like to let the app crash. I think it's more frustrating for the user if he clicks and nothing happens as opposed to the app crashing. If it crashes, it's clear then what has happened, there's an issue, as opposed to nothing happening and leaving the user flabbergasted...

Comment: @AndreiBogdan please take a look, I edited my answer with additional info

Comment: Thanks man! This should be documented on Firebase's Test Crash page....

Comment: Enabling non-fatal logging this way works for this specific crash mentioned in the OP, but from my experience only because we are throwing it ourselves. If we leave out the `throw` keyword, it still "crashes" (red screen for widget build error) but it's not getting reported. Any idea how to fix this?